# What is a top level class in Java?

Tags: java

- What is a top level class in Java?
- What is the definition of a top level class in Java?

I know that this is a basic question, but I could not find a clear and simple answer for this question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's simply any class that's not a nested class. If your file is Foo.java, and your class is Foo, then it's a top level class.

```
// in Foo.java:

public class Foo { // top level class

    public static class NestedBar { // nested class
    }

}
```

I had always thought this was an informal term, but it turns out it's actually [defined in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html):

> A top level class is a class that is not a nested class.
>
> A nested class is any class whose declaration occurs within the body of another class or interface.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the JLS link which has all the details.

Comment: That means that a top level class can be a child of another class (inheritance)? For example: class Sub extends Another { }  => Sub is still always a top level class? Thank you

Comment: @armin.miedl Yes, top-level just refers to where in the code it is, not where in the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

The definition posted is correct, maybe another definition could be: a top-level class is the defined class with the same name of the file '.java' where it's in. however, just as an observation, for the case showed, a nested (not a top-level) 'static' class has the same behavior of a top-level class, in terms of the interaction with the instance members of the class where it has been nested.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15646912)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I've remembered this case and haven't paid attention to the answer of the question, so sorry for this. I'll try to answer better. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

A `.java` file can contain more than one class. At most, one of them can have a `public` access modifier, and the others must be `default` access modifier. They can be also `final` or `abstract` but not both at once. So, each non-nested independent class defined in a `.java` file is *a top-level class*.

For example, each class is a top-level class in following example.

```
public class Animal {  
    private String name; 
} 
class Animal2 {}
```

Comment: A `.java` file can have multiple public classes, it just can't have multiple top-level public classes. And the JLS doesn't actually _require_ that restriction; it allows it, and I believe all/most compilers use it.