# Why using enclosing class's instance, the static nested class can't be instantiated?

Tags: java, class, static, nested, inner-classes

I know that static members of a class can be directly accessed without the need for the instance of the enclosing class.

```
class Outer
{
    static int a = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(a);//without using instance
    }
}
```

But, the same static members can also be accessed with the instance of the class as well. As they are shared across all the instances of the particular class.

```
class Outer
{
    static int a = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Outer().a);//with using instance
    }
}
```

All these seem fine only with **static variables and static methods** and when attempted with **static nested class**, it results in compilation ***error: qualified new of static class***.

```
class Outer
{
    static class Nested
    {
        int a = 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Outer().new Nested().a);
    }
}
```

Similar to other static members, even this should have been possible. Isn't it?
Are there any internal details that I am missing out on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tells us:

> **Note:** A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.

A [top-level class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41714579/12323248) is simply a class that is not nested within another class.

So, a static nested class is not different from a not nested classes. In your example `Nested` is not different from `Outer` in it's behaviour; it could be declared just outside `Outer`. Therefore `new Outer().new Nested()` is not valid syntax. Nesting a static class is just for packaging convenience, therefore `new Outer.Nested()` works, just like e.g. `new java.util.ArrayList<String>()` works.